# Addition in polar form

Tags: complex-numbers

$$u_{1}(t) = 120\sqrt{2}e^{j5000t}$$
$$u_{2}(t) = -j160\sqrt{2}e^{j5000t}$$

I need to add these two values, so:

$u(t) = u_{1}(t) + u_{2}(t) = (120 - j160)\sqrt{2}e^{j5000t} = ...$

What next? How can I do this without changing the form of the numbers?

Comment: $u_2(t)$ is not in polar form right now. Also, addition is easier in standard form, whereas multiplication is easier in polar form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $120-j160$ in polar form; that is, find the $r>0$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ such that
$$120-j160=re^{j\theta}.$$
Then you'll have
$$u(t)= (120 - j160)\sqrt{2}e^{j5000t} = re^{j\theta}\cdot\sqrt{2}e^{j5000t}=(r\sqrt{2})e^{j(\theta+5000t)}.$$